# Storage size is unknown

Tags: c, memory, struct, size, storage

I'm trying to learn C, but I'm having trouble with the whole memory allocation that comes with it. I'm lost on where to create space. This is the header I was supplied with.

```
typedef struct list_item {
    char *value;
    struct list_item *next;
    struct list_item *prev;
} list_item_t; 

typedef struct single_list {
    list_item_t *head;
    list_item_t *tail;
} slist_t;

void init(slist_t *list);
```

I implemented the the init function with:

```
void init(slist_t *list){
    list->head = (list_item_t *) malloc(sizeof(list_item_t));
    list->tail = (list_item_t *) malloc(sizeof(list_item_t));
}
```

but I use run the code with

```
int main(){
    struct list_t test;
    init(test);
    return 0;
```

I get an error saying the storage size of 'test' isn't known. I know I have to define the space for test but where should I write this and how? Thanks guys.

Comment: Where is `struct list_t` defined? You are showing a type definition called `slist_t`.

Comment: You should not use suffix `_t` for custom types. Also, do not cast the result of `malloc` & friends in C.

Comment: Also, `init ` takes a pionter to `slist_t`, not a `struct list_t`.  (Not commenting on the difference between `slist_t` and `list_t`, but on the fact that one is a pointer and the other is not.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace:

```
struct list_t test;
```

with

```
slist_t test;
```

Your type is named `struct single_list` and you can also use the alias you created named `slist_t`.

Note that you then want to pass a pointer to the object:

```
init(&test);
```

Comment: @Forrest4096 I added an edit in the same time you put your comment

Comment: yep thats more like it